# What equation will convert implied yield volatility to implied price volatility?

Tags: options, fixed-income, interest-rates, implied-volatility, bond

I am trying to figure out how to turn implied yield volatility of a short-term interest rate into implied price volatility. Is there an equation to do this?

I have come across the equation for a bond:
(price_vol = yield_vol*modified_duration*forward_yield)
But, I do not believe this is correct for a STIR option.

Comment: This seems to work very well for at-the-money options: yield_vol*(100-futures_price)

Answer (score 1):

***percent price change ≈ −modified duration × yield change***

**Example**

- Consider a bond whose modified duration is 11.54 with a
  yield of 10%.
- If the yield increases instantaneously from 10% to
  10.1%, the approximate percentage price change will be:

−11.54 × 0.001 = −0.01154 = −1.154%.

**Source**

https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~lyuu/finance1/2008/20080227.pdf